# How to set scheduled reports in Vtiger crm 6.1.0 version?

Tags: vtiger, cron-task

I am using v-tiger 6.1.0 beta version for my site.I  set a schedule report, but the mail is not delivered on the specified time.Also the 'Scheduler' inside the "crm settings->other settings->scheduler" is not working.
I set a CRON JOB inside the webmin for the functioning of the scheduled report.Still it's not working.
Is it necessary to set the CRON JOB in the webmin for the functioning of scheduled report inside the v-tiger.If that is the case then which file is set in the command field.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CRON job is necessary for the reports to be delivered.
Also, please check your cron sheduler if its working fine.